# Android Shared Preference: How to get values from String set?

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I have created a String set called 'nameSet' in which I have saved many names.

```
Set<String> nameSet=new HashSet<String>(); //declared as global

public void loadAllData()
{
    nameSet.add("Matt");
    nameSet.add("John");
    nameSet.add("Mike");
    nameSet.add("Gilbert");
    nameSet.add("Kyle");
    nameSet.add("Jim");
    editor.putStringSet("SET1",nameSet); 
    // do I need to declare 'SET1' as a String set beforehand?
    editor.commit();
}
```

Now, I only want to retrieve any one random value or the first value from 'SET1'; I have written the code for it, but it still gives me errors:

```
public String getData()
{
    Set<String> name=new HashSet<String>();
    name=pref.getStringSet("SET1",null);
    if(name!=null)
    {
        for(String i:name)
        {
            PersonName=i; //does this line retrieve only one name?
        }
    }
    return PersonName; //PersonName is a String passed to another activity
}
```

Errors Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.demosquareout.compaq.algarferrariapp, PID: 6500
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demosquareout.compaq.Pingapp/com.demosquareout.compaq.Pingapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void PingApp.fragments.PersonDetails.loadAllData()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void PingApp.fragments.PersonDetails.loadAllData()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at algarferrari.fragments.PersonList.onCreateView(PersonList.java:56)
                                                                                        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2281)
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:984)
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1164)
                                                                                        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1557)
                                                                                        at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:326)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6942)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3276)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

In 'PersonDetails' activity's constructor I have called `loadAllData()`. Please note that I have changed the location of calling `loadAllData()`.

```
public Person Details(Context context)
{
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
    loadAllData();
}
```

Comment: _but it still gives me errors_ what errors?

Comment: NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke loadAllData() on a null object reference

Comment: Can you add the code that invokes `loadAllData()`?

Comment: I am invoking loadAllData() in onCreateView of another Activity 'PersonList'

Comment: n1.loadAllData(); //where n1 is an object of 'PersnDetails' Activity containing loadAllData() method

Comment: I debugged my program, the error i mentioned abv seems to be coming from loadAllData() method only..What should be done?

Comment: The code you provided doesn't tell much. Show your errors

Comment: I have added the errors logcat abv

Comment: Hey @sam88, Where is `loadAllData()` invoked? Can you share that code too?

Comment: I am invoking loadAllData() in onCreateView of another Activity 'PersonList'

Comment: n1.loadAllData(); //where n1 is an object of 'PersnDetails' Activity containing loadAllData() method

Answer (score 0):

@sam88, I'm a little bit confused about your code because you are trying your code in **onCreateView** in the **Activity**, maybe there something happens wrong to Activity framework.

I think in your code **editor** object is getting null.

Try this code may be it will solve your problem.

```
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    editor.putStringSet("SET1",nameSet); 

    editor.commit();
```

Here, **mContext** is the context of your activity.

Comment: I have edited my code above to invoke loadAllData() in 'PersonDetails' Activity's constructor..it is the same activity which contains loadAllData()

Comment: Can you please share the code of whole activity? And tell me on which line you getting the NullPoinrtException.

Comment: That may not be possible, kindly accommodate with the given code..The code provided has enough material..thanks